# Powershell script running for SQL Server 2008R2 but not for higher version

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am running below Powershell script from a SQL Server 2008R2 machine. The purpose of the script is to create SQL Job on all the mentioned SQL Server instances remotely in one go. The servername,instancename and PortNumber has been mentioned through the notepad. It is able to do so on a 2008R2 instance but not on SQL Server 2012. I always have a doubt that whether powershell scripts depends on the SQL Server version or not?

It will be great if somebody can help me clearing my doubt and resolving the issue.

Error Message:

The below error message keeps on repeating for all the parameters that we are setting for a job like OwnerLoginName, Subsystem,Command etc etc

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "SetParent failed for Job 'SQL Services Restarted Aler
"
At E:\Sachin\create-SQLJOB_AllInstances_V1.ps1:18 char:16
+ $j = new-object <<<<  ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job') ($s.JobServer,'SQL Services Restarted Aler
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Property 'Description' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At E:\Sachin\create-SQLJOB_AllInstances_V1.ps1:19 char:4
+ $j. <<<< Description = 'Alert to identify the SQL Services Restart'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Description:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\Sachin\create-SQLJOB_AllInstances_V1.ps1:21 char:10
+ $j.Create <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Create:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Thanks in advance.`

```
    function CreateSQLJob{
    param (
    [string]$svr,
    [string]$inst,
    [string]$port
    )
    foreach ($instancename in $inst)
    {
    $ConnectionString = "data source = $inst,$port; initial catalog = master; trusted_connection = true;"
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
    $s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server')
    $s.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $j = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job') ($s.JobServer,'SQL Services Restarted Alert')
    $j.Description = 'Alert to identify the SQL Services Restart'
    $j.OwnerLoginName = 'sa'
    $j.Create()
   $js = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobStep') ($j,'Step 01')
   $js.SubSystem = 'TransactSql'
   $js.Command = "IF(SELECT DATEDIFF(MI,Crdate,GETDATE()) FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE NAME='TEMPDB')<=2
   BEGIN
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
   @profile_name='XXX',
   @recipients=N'xxx@xxx.com',
   @subject=N'SQL Services Restarted on on Server - $inst',
   @body=N'This is an informational message only: SQL services possibly restarted on this server. Please restart any dependent application services after verifying status with DBA Team first.'
  END"
  $js.OnSuccessAction = 'QuitWithSuccess'
  $js.OnFailAction = 'GoToStep'
  $js.OnFailStep=2
  $js.Create()
  $SQLJobStep2 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Agent.JobStep -argumentlist $j,"Failure Notification"
  $SQLJobStep2.Command = "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name = 'XXX',
  @recipients='xxx@xxx.com',
  @subject = 'SQL Services Restarted Alert job - FAILED on $inst',
  @body = 'Hi Team,<br><br> 
            SQL Services Restarted Alert job failed . <br><br>
                     Thank You.', 
 @body_format = 'HTML' ;"
 $SQLJobStep2.DatabaseName = "master"
 $SQLJobStep2.OnSuccessAction = "QuitWithFailure"
 $SQLJobStep2.OnFailAction = "QuitWithFailure"
 $SQLJobStep2.Create()
 $jsid = $js.ID
 $j.ApplyToTargetServer($inst)
 $j.StartStepID = $jsid
 $j.Alter()
 $jsch = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobSchedule') ($j,'Sched 01')
 $jsch.FrequencyTypes = 'AutoStart'
 $jsch.ActiveStartDate = get-date
 $jsch.Create()
 write-host "SQL Services Restarted Alert Job created on server $inst"
 }
 }
 $servers = Get-Content 'E:\Sachin\SQL_Servers1.txt'

 foreach ($sv in $servers) {
 $srvr = $sv.Split(",")
 $server = $srvr[0]
 $instance = $srvr[1]
 $port = $srvr[2]

 CreateSQLJob $server $instance $port
 }`
```

Comment: There are differences in the powershell provider between 2008R2 and 2012. We had to include different ones depending on which we were connecting to. Sorry, no longer have access to source for details.

Comment: What version of Management Studio is installed on the SQL 2008 R2 machine?  Try running the script from a machine that has SQL 2012 or better management studio installed and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @MichaelGreen Thanks for the response. So you wanted to say that i  need to install a SQL Server 2012 Powershell Provider on SQL Server 2008R2 machine, if I want to make this script work for 2012??? Or something else needs to be done....

Comment: @JonathanFite Thanks for the response. I will check the SSMS Version and let you know. Also I will check if the script works in 2012 machine as intended....

Comment: Yes, I seem to remember that's what we ended up doing.

Comment: @MichaelGreen I installed the necessary SQL Server 2012 tools like Windows Powershell extensions for SQL server 2012 an SMOs for 2012 but still it is showing same error. Do I need to install SQL Server 2012 or SSMS 2012 on the SQL 2008 R2 machine also??

Comment: @JonathanFite SSMS version is 2008R2. I ran the script on the machine having SQL Server 2012. It was able to fetch the details from the 2012 machines but I cant move the script to that machine as it doesnot have the connectivity to all the other SQL Server instances in the network. Is there any way I can make the script run on the same 2008R2 machine???

Comment: @sachin-SQLServernewbiee, You could probably install SSMS 2012 or later on the SQL 2008 R2 server and then the script should be able to work from there.

Comment: @JonathanFite After installing SSMS 2014 and the necessary tools for it like Powershell Extensions, SMO, SQLCLR types for 2014. When I am running the script it is throwing the same error. Do I need to update Powershell version as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first installed SSMS 2014 on the same machine having SQL Server 2008R2.

Then I installed the Powershell Provider for SQL Server 2014.

After that I am able to fetch the details from the higher versions of SQL Server like 2012 as well.

There is no need to update Powershell.